# Does node_modules’s size affect to ionic app’s size?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, node-modules

node_modules's size is 230MB and app's size is 34MB(with crosswalk).
Does reduce app's size if reduce node_modules's size?
Does node_modules's size affect to app's size?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're doing with the dependencies. You can have client side dependencies, such as Angular, which will be in the final application packages. You can also have building dependencies, such as some parts of the Cordova platform, that will be used only during application packaging, but will not be merged in the file that will be uploaded to the app stores.

There's a lot of good material online on Ionic 2 improvements for production apps. I recommend starting with this one: https://blog.khophi.co/optimize-ionic-2-app-production/.